# A priori estimate of an inhomogeneous p-Laplace equation with Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, norms, p-laplace

I'm currently working on this Dirichlet problem:

\begin{cases}
div(\sigma |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) = f &\quad  {in }~ \Omega\\
u = g &\quad in~\partial\Omega
\end{cases}

with $\sigma \in L^{\infty}_{+}(\Omega)$, boundary $g \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$.

I think I've already proved that this problem has a unique solution, but I don't know how to prove the following a priori estimate

\begin{align}
||{u}||_{W^{1,p}} \leq C ({||g||}_{W^{1,p}} + {||f||}_{L^2}^{\frac{1}{p-1}})
\end{align}

This estimate is mentioned in this paper
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7399/da07c625d51aa7ee72840789916b036019d2.pdf
(second page; equation (1.4))
but without giving proof. I guess it's seen "easy", but I just don't know how to get there. I know how to conclude an a priori estimate in the case $f=0$ or $g=0$, but since p-Laplace operator isn't linear, this doesn't help and I'm really clueless know. I hope someone can help me with with.

As far as i thought i can use the Poincaré inequality since $u - g \in W^{1,p}_0$:

\begin{align}
||u||_{W^{1,p}} &= ||u||_{L^p} + ||\nabla u||_{L^p}\\
& \leq ||g||_{L^p} + ||u - g||_{L^p} + ||\nabla u||_{L^p}\\
& \leq ||g||_{L^p} + C||\nabla(u - g)||_{L^p} + ||\nabla u||_{L^p}
\end{align}

The problem is that i can't find an upper bound for $||\nabla u||_{L^p}$ using $f$...

The inequality in the paper that i found implies that i should found something like

\begin{align}
||\nabla u||^p_{L^p} \leq ||f||_{L^2}~||\nabla u||_{L^p}
\end{align}

which only be valid, when the solution u is in $W^{1,p}_0$...

I hope someone can help me with with this...

Edit: Using fedjas advice i got

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} f~(u - g) &= \int_{\Omega} div(\sigma |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) (u - g)\\
&= \int_{\Omega} \sigma |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u \nabla (u - g)\\
&\leq ||f||_{L^2} ||u - g||_{L^p} \\
&\leq ||f||_{L^2} ~C ||\nabla (u - g)||_{L^p}
\end{align}

Now if i would have $||\nabla (u - g)||_{L^p}^p \leq  \int_{\Omega} f~(u - g)$ it would be good... BUT I dont know how to get there...

$%\int_{\Omega} f~(u - g) \leq ||\nabla (u - g)||_{L^p}^p$

because the mapping $ x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex we have always

$|x|^p \geq |y|^p + p |y|^{p-2}y (x-y)$ (characterization with first derivation)

and with $x = \nabla (u - g)$ and $y = \nabla u$ it follows

$|\nabla (u - g)|^p \geq |\nabla u|^p - p|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u \nabla g$

don't know if it's useful here, but its valid for $p \geq 1$.

Furthermore i know that

$\frac{1}{p} (\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p - |\nabla g|^p) \leq \int_{\Omega} f~(u - g)$

Because the solution u is the minimizer of the functional:
$J(v) = \frac{1}{p} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla v|^2 - \int_{\Omega} fv$ for all $v \in W^{1,p}_g$ (space with needed boundary values) and therefore $J(u)\leq J(g)$

Nevertheless i still don't see how to put all of this together to achieve the desired result... :/

Comment: Play $u-g\in W_0^{1,p}$ against $f$, use the equation, and integrate by parts. I hope $p$ is good enough for the Sobolev embedding $W^{1,p}\subset L^2$.

Comment: Thanks for comment! :) I tried to follow your advice, but i am not sure if i 100% understood it (espacally the sobolev embedding part?). I edited my post and tried to do what you meant, but as you can see I still dont know how to get there

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are totally new to such estimates, so let me show you the old $\varepsilon$ vs $C_\varepsilon$ trick. If you need to estimate some product $xy$, you can write $|xy|\le |x|^2+|y|^2$, but sometimes you would prefer a smaller constant on $x$ (that you would later subtract from the other side) and do not really care how big one you get on $y$. In this case you can write 
$$
|xy|=|(\varepsilon^{1/2} x)(\varepsilon^{-1/2}y)|\le \varepsilon |x|^2+\varepsilon^{-1}|y|^2=\varepsilon |x|^2+C_\varepsilon |y|^2
$$
You can do it with any positive powers, so you can equally well write
$$
|x|^a|y|^b\le\varepsilon|x|^{a+b}+C_\varepsilon |y|^{a+b}
$$
(of course, $C_\varepsilon$ here depends on $a,b$ as well).

Now, you have your identity
$$
\int_\Omega f(u-g)=\int_\Omega\sigma|\nabla u|^{p-2}\langle\nabla u,\nabla u-\nabla g\rangle
$$
Rewrite it as 
$$
\int_\Omega\sigma|\nabla u|^{p}=\int_\Omega\sigma|\nabla u|^{p-2}\langle\nabla u,\nabla g\rangle+\int_\Omega f(u-g)\le
\int_\Omega\sigma|\nabla u|^{p-1}|\nabla g|+\int_\Omega |f||u-g|
$$
We certainly need $\sigma\ge \sigma_0>0$ in $\Omega$ (otherwise you can easily blow up everything). So, we have
$$
\sigma_0\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^{p}\le \int_\Omega\sigma|\nabla u|^{p-1}|\nabla g|+\int_\Omega |f||u-g|
$$
Now play $\varepsilon$ vs $C\varepsilon$ and recall that $\sigma\le\sigma_1<+\infty$:
$$
\sigma|\nabla u|^{p-1}|\nabla g|\le \sigma_1(\varepsilon|\nabla u|^{p}+C_\varepsilon|\nabla g|^p)\,.
$$
Assuming that $W^{1,p}\subset L^2$, we also have
$$
\int_\Omega |f||u-g|\le \|f\|_2\|u-g\|_2\le 
\|f\|_2\|u-g\|_{1,p}=(\|f\|^{1/(p-1)}_2)^{p-1}\|u-g\|_{1,p}
\\
\le 
\varepsilon \|u-g\|_{1,p}^p+C_\varepsilon \|f\|_2^{p/(p-1)}.
$$
Recalling the bound 
$$
\|u-g\|^p_{1,p}\le C[\|\nabla u|^p_p+\|g\|_{1,p}^p]\,,
$$
we get 
$$
\sigma_0\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^{p}\le
\sigma_1[\varepsilon\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{p}+C_\varepsilon\int_{\Omega}|\nabla g|^p]+\varepsilon C[\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{p}+\|g\|_{1,p}^p]+ CC_\varepsilon \|f\|_2^{p/(p-1)}
$$
Now choose $\varepsilon$ so small that after moving all the terms with $\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^p$ from the right to the left, you still have some positive coefficient on the LHS.

That's all. I presented it with all details and spelled out what exactly is needed for what step since it looks like you are seeing this standard mumbo-jumbo for the first time. Try to to it yourself next time.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very very much! Yes, I am new too such estimates and this functional analysis stuff, so I am very gratefull for your detailed answer. But I still have one question regarding your mentioned bound $||u - g||^p_{1,p} \leq C [|| \nabla u||^p + ||g||^p_{1,p}]$... Can you explain why it is true? Because in my eyes it's not - at least not for arbitrary u and g? :/ I only have $||u - g||^p_{1,p} \leq C ||\nabla u - \nabla g||^p_p \leq C ( ||\nabla u||_p + || \nabla g ||_p)^p$

Comment: @ANZM91 What do you mean? $\|g\|_{1.p}^p\approx \|g\|_p^p+\|\nabla g\|_p^p$, so my RHS is *larger* than yours (and $\|g\|_p$ matters, by the way: think of large constants).

Comment: Why is it larger? I have $(||\nabla u||_p + ||g||_p + ||\nabla g||_p ) ^p$ - the p-th power of the sum. Or is $| x - y| ^p \leq |x|^p + |y|^p $ always true? Sorry, but I am a bit confused at the moment >.<

Comment: @ANZM91 Analysis is not algebra. If $a,b,p>0$, then we have $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ for all practical purposes. My RHS is larger because it also includes $\|g\|_p^p$, which you lost somewhere (and it matters!).

Comment: Ahhhh, maybe you did mean this way?
\begin{align*}
||u - g||^p_{1,p} &\leq C_p || \nabla u - \nabla g ||^p_{p} \\
&\leq C_p(||\nabla u||_p + ||\nabla g||_p)^p \\
&= C_p \sum_{i=0}^{p} \binom{p}{i} ||\nabla u||_p^{p - i}||\nabla g||_p^i \\
&\leq C_p \binom{p}{p/2} (||\nabla u||^p_p + ||\nabla g||^p_p) \\
&\leq C (||\nabla u||^p_p + ||\nabla g||^p_p + ||\nabla g||) \\
&= \leq C (||\nabla u||^p_p + ||\nabla g||^p_{1,p})
\end{align*}

By the way: In my case I have $p\geq 1$ so $W^{1,p} \subset L^2$ isnt working, is it? What do i have to change then?

Comment: @ANZM91 The very first inequality in your chain is wrong: think of $u-g\equiv 1$

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I hope I dont annoy you, but how can
$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ be true? $(1+2)^2 = 9 \not= 1^2 + 2^2 = 4$ ?
I feel a bit dumb know, can't get the point >.<

And why is the first inequality wrong? I just used the Poincaé inequality because $u - g \in W^{1,p}_0$...
And I again don't know what you mean with $ u - g = 1$ (constantly 1 nearly everywhere on $\Omega$?

Comment: @ANZM91 Ah, yes. You used the condition that the difference is in $W^{1,p}_0$ and I was thinking of $W^{1,p}$. Then you are right here and everything works as you said. As to the other question, $4=9$ for all practical purposes (i.e. they are the same up to a constant factor).

Comment: Ah ok! And thank you again!!! :) You can't believe how grateful I am for your fast and good help!

But regarding my with "Assuming $W^{1,p} \subset L^2$:
In my case I have $p \geq 1$ and for $p<2$ it doesnt work, does it?
What do I have to change?

Do I have to estimate this way using hoelder inequality?

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} f (u-g) \leq ||f||_{p/(p-1)} ||u - g||_p
\end{align*}

Comment: @ANZM91 That would require $f\in L^{p/(p-1)}$. If it is there, you are fine. However, $W_{1,p}\subset L^2$ if $\frac 1p\le \frac 12+\frac 1n$ ($n$ is the dimension of the space and we assume that $\Omega$ is bounded), so you have some leeway here (all the way up to $p=1$ in $\mathbb R^2$). So, you have to check your setup to see if $p$ is within the required range or not to use just the $L^2$ bound for $f$.

Comment: hello fedja,

my setup is $\Omega \subset R^2$ so everything good. but another question came to my mind:

why we can easy say that

\begin{align}
||f||_{L^2} ||u - g||_{L^2} \leq ||f||_{L^2} ||u - g||_{W^{1,p}}
\end{align}

isn't there a constant missing?

or is $||u - g||_{L^2} \leq ||u - g||_{W^{1,p}}$? At least as far as i know $||u - g||_{L^2} \geq ||u - g||_{L^p}$

Comment: @ANZM91 Yes, there is a constant missing :-)